# How do you read a seriers of numbers from input and store them into an array?

Tags: java, arrays

So I've been trying to do this homework all day and I still can't figure out how to write a method to read in a line of numbers and save them into an array. This is what I tried but doesn't work

```
public static int [] readData()

    throws java.io.IOException
    {

    int [] rArray = new int[15];

    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

    String data = br.readLine();
    StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(data);

    String d = str.nextToken();
    int num = Integer.parseInt(d);

    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
    rArray[i] = num;
    }


    return rArray;

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Since this is homework ... here's a (BIG) hint.

Look at your code, and figure out  how many times `parseInt` gets called for a single line of input.  Do you get the answer "one time"?  If not, read the code again!

Comment: so i need to pass parseInt 15 times 0.o

Comment: You need to call `parseInt` to 15 times per line (depending on how many numbers you actually have on each line).  But that doesn't mean that you need 15 separate call statements.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting only one toke using nextToken(). But there are more tokens. So you need to iterate and take that. But please make sure it doesnt go ArrayIndexOutOfBounds because you have declared only array of 15 integers. Please change the code as below.

```
int index = 0;
while(str.hasMoreTokens()){
String d = str.nextToken();
    int num = Integer.parseInt(d);
    rArray[index] = num;
    inde++;
}
```

Comment: @raddykish - we don't do the students' basic programming homework for them.  We give them helpful hints so that they can figure it out for themselves.  It is in the students' best interest that they learn by doing their own homework.

Answer (score 0):

You can to know the number of times that the tokenizer's `nextToken` method can be called before it generates an exception and build the array.

```
StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(data);
int[] rArray = new int[str.countTokens()];
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

u can achieve it Using `String array` and `Split()` method with `readLine()`.